# RequireJS and HTML5 WebWorkers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-worker

I have this code, suprisingly, CDN links work with importScripts. However, I would prefer to re-use the scripts that have already been loaded by RequireJS on the main UI thread. I could use importScripts to import the RequireJS library, but I believe that this would be a new instance of RequireJS..is there anyway to share the same instance somehow?

```
     //I don't want to have to reimport these scripts:

      /*

      if(typeof importScripts === 'function'){
         importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js');
         importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js');
      }

     */

       //...I would rather just use the existing RequireJS scripts

      if(typeof importScripts === 'function'){
         importScripts('/js/vendor/require.js');
       }

    //require is now defined, but React and ReactDOM aren't loaded

    require(['react','reactDOM'],function(React,ReactDOM){

        onmessage = function(msg) {

            var ContactItem = React.createFactory(React.createClass({

                propTypes: {
                    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                },

                render: function () {
                    return (
                        React.createElement('li', {className: 'Contact'},
                            React.createElement('h2', {className: 'Contact-name'}, this.props.name)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }));

            var str = React.renderToString(ContactItem({name:'charlie'}));
            postMessage(str);

        };

    });
```

so to summarize the above - I can import RequireJS into the WebWorker, but it will not be the same instance of RequireJS as that on the main UI thread, so I cannot use the scripts loaded with that instance of RequireJS - so what is the best thing to do assuming that my assessment is correct? Or is it?

Comment: Web workers are "shared-nothing" by design; you can't get the "same instance" of something running in a browser window/tab.

Comment: yeah thanks, that was a very hopeful part of my question